# Получить максимальные значения из таблицы

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, запрос

Есть таблица `id` и поля `f1, f2, p1, p2, team, m_id`,  в первых четырех полях значения в цифрах, а последний матч, то есть этот матч может быть у некоторых записей одинаковый. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно выбрать по 2 команды одного матча, но при этом надо взять, где значение `p1` и `p2` или `f1` и `f2` больше всего, то есть нужно найти 2 самых больших значения и вывести в виде:

> Team p1 m_id
>   Team p2 m_id

Написал начало запроса, но он пока не дотягивает до того что надо:

```
SELECT id, id_m, max(f1), max(f2), max(p1), max(p2)  
FROM   matchs 
WHERE  id_m IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY id_m
```

Поля: id, team, p1, p2, f1, f2 , m_id. Эти данные постоянно обновляются тоесть каждый матчи и его значения,
Допустим m_id = 7
Нужно: team p1 с id_m 7 и team p2 c  id_m 7, и так с каждого id_m по два матча с большими значениями

```
id team      p1  p2  f1  f2  m_id
1  bovaria    4   5   3   3  idm8    
2  bovaria1   4   4  90   9  idm8    
3  bovaria2   5   5   8  80  idm8    
4  bovaria4   6   6   6   6  idm8     
5  bovaria8  60  68   9   9  idm9    
6  bovaria9  18  83   9   9  idm9
```

Выбрать:

```
2  bovaria1  f1=90 idm8
3  bovaria2  f2=80 idm8
```

И

```
5 bovaria8 p1=60 idm9
6 bovaria9 p2=83 idm9
```

Comment: два самых больших: из разных строк? в сумме? корень из произведения?

Comment: у вас сейчас в принципе выводятся все строки с уникальными значениями id_m, только у всех их f1,f2,p1,p2 будут одинаковыми, т.к. вы говорите "Выбрать id, id_m и максимальные значения остальных полей для всех строк, объединенных по полю id_m". Переводите все запросы на русский язык - и будете сразу замечать что вы "сказали" совсем не то что нужно

Comment: А БД у вас какая?

Comment: @Viktorov, прекратите страдать ерундой, пожалуйста.

Comment: Отделять ключевые слова от аргументов, образуя какую-то семантически ничего не обозначающую структуру(2 столбика) - плохая идея.

Comment: @Jony8002, из вопроса до сих пор неясно, что вы хотите получить. Добавьте пример данных в таблице и желаемый результат.

Comment: @vp_arth, Нужно найти в одном матче 2 команды, в которых самые большие значение f1, f2 или p1 и p2, тоесть одно из двух и самые большие и вывести по 2 команды одного матча с самыми большими значениями

Comment: Не надо объяснять своими словами. Добавьте [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/753961/edit) примеры данных(несколько строк) и что вы хотите из них получить(строки результата).

Comment: @vp_arth, все описал выше.

Comment: "Допустим, у меня есть строки `1 2 'm1'`, `5 3 'm1'` и `7 1 'm1'`, мне нужно получить то-то и то-то, что-бы получилось `7 3 'm1'`" Неужели так сложно привести [mcve]?

Comment: Просто добавьте пример заполненной таблицы, хотя бы строки 3-4  и пример выведенного результата.

Comment: @vp_arth, описал сверху, если что-то не понятно то пишите

Comment: Спасибо, в таком виде у вопроса гораздо больше шансов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Основная сложность данной задачи в том, что в результирующую выборку в одну колонку попадают результаты из разных колонок. Это говорит, скорее всего, о неверной структуре данных.*

Решение "в лоб".

Собираем все максимальные значения(на самом деле, стираем все остальные):

```
SELECT id, team,
 if(p1=(SELECT MAX(p1) FROM t), p1, NULL) p1,
 if(p2=(SELECT MAX(p2) FROM t), p2, NULL) p2,
 if(f1=(SELECT MAX(f1) FROM t), f1, NULL) f1,
 if(f2=(SELECT MAX(f2) FROM t), f2, NULL) f2,
 m_id
FROM t;
```

И формируем выборку:

```
SELECT id, team,
  if(p1 is not null, 'p1',
    if(p2 is not null, 'p2',
      if(f1 is not null, 'f1', 'f2'))) field,
  COALESCE(p1, p2, f1, f2) val,
  m_id
FROM (SELECT id, team,
 if(p1=(SELECT MAX(p1) FROM t), p1, NULL) p1,
 if(p2=(SELECT MAX(p2) FROM t), p2, NULL) p2,
 if(f1=(SELECT MAX(f1) FROM t), f1, NULL) f1,
 if(f2=(SELECT MAX(f2) FROM t), f2, NULL) f2,
 m_id
FROM t) maxes
WHERE COALESCE(p1, p2, f1, f2) is not null;
```

Результат:

```
 id, team,     field, val, m_id
 2,  bovaria1, f1,    90,  idm8
 3,  bovaria2, f2,    80,  idm8
 5,  bovaria8, p1,    60,  idm9
 6,  bovaria9, p2,    83,  idm9
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/343573/1)

Comment: Спасибо огромное)) Извини что долго не заходил,  можно к тебе обратиться если будут не большие вопросы в будущем ?

Comment: Вопросы лучше задавать тут же с помощью кнопки "Задать вопрос"

Comment: извини что только сейчас отписался, твой вариант не очень хорошо работает, из всех записей он показывает только 4, а их там должно быть по двое матчей на каждый id_m, тоесть где id_m общий там берем две большие записи, фотку то что получается с вашим запросом сверху.